Beginner circuit design review request
Summary:
I am trying to design a LED thingy and I am asking for a review of the schematic and PCB.
It is my first time doing either schematic or PCB.
Edit in response to comment: The thing is supposed to be a kind of toy. Somewhere between a mood light and disco lighting. It will have some limited interactivity (like changing brightness, switching between light patterns, changing speed, potentially reacting to loud noises in some way, whatever I can think of). It is supposed to rest on a desk and the main body is going to be maybe 12x12x3cm, but the design is not finished yet. It will have a WS2812 LED matrix on the top surface.
Explanation:
As a learning exercise (and if all goes to plan, as a Christmas present), I am trying to make a Neopixel LED gadget thing.
I have no formal electronics training, but have read lots of datasheets, blogs, ... so I know just enough to confidently point the gun right at my foot.
The plan is to have a PCB manufactured and directly solder a Raspberry Pi Pico to it, then use wires to connect to various breakout boards in different parts of a self-designed case (WIP).
I have tried to learn Kicad and came up with the following schematic. I hope it is understandable. Links to datasheets are at the bottom.

J1/PWR_TOGGLE is a touch module in toggle mode as the soft-off botton. This is powered directly from USB voltage.
This enables the pico power supply circuit (3V3_EN) to provide 3.3V to most of the rest of the circuit.
J2-J6 are the same touch modules, but powered from 3.3V. They will be used to trigger various software functions.
The whole thing should be powered over USB-C.
Since it will have a few dozen WS2812B, I need to be careful about current draw.
I want to use the RP2040's ADC to measure/monitor the voltage divider on the USB-C CC1/CC2 pins.
According to the USB-C spec, table 4-25 and 4-36, I should be able to determine wether I can draw 500mA or 1500mA or 3000mA.
Then use code to limit the maximum (cumulative) LED brightness so to not exceed this.
However, CC pins are 'live' before I get power from the USB port and the ADC pins are not marked as fault tolerant.
If I read the USB-C spec correctly, the CC pins should only source at most about 0.7mA, so hopefully not enough to destroy the Pico, but if the ADC pin sinks current while unpowered, it might upset the USB-C detection enough to prevent upstream from switching on power.
So I figured, I needed to protect them and put those BSS138 in there. When they are on, the source would float up to at most 2.2V, so I thought I could switch them with the 5V power toggle.
That way they should still be on sufficiencly to allow for measurement (RDS_on at less than 10 Ohm at V_GS of about 2.5V).
But this area feels a bit iffy and I get the feeling I am missing something.
The TC74VHCT04AFT is in there to level shift the 3.3V GPIO to 5V for Neopixel and Mosfet gate. I have used it successfully as a level shifter before and it worked.
The LED power gate is there to switch off the LEDs completely when in soft-off, since they are supposed to draw around 1mA per piece even when unlit.
I expect the LEDs to use at most 2.9A and, from the numbers and graphs in the datasheet, I guesstimated the AO3401A to have a worst case RDS_on of about 120mOhm when warm.
This should be barely within the spec, but I decided to double up to be safe and limit losses.
Mic1: I hope to use the microphone to detect clapping or maybe even music beat and react to it (very) eventually, if I ever get around to it.
Now, after all this rambling, my questions are:

as the schematic is, will I fry my little pi or the other components?
is this a viable design in principle?
do I need a whole bunch of pull-down resistors at U1A, U1C or the gates of Q3/Q4? I am not sure how floaty the RP2040 pins are when not powered. I suppose I could fit a couple of SMD resistors, but I would have to source them. I have all the other parts.
do I need any fuses or similar? My thought is, since I am planning to use the full available 3 Amps of USB bus power and the upstream port is supposed to limit the current, any current limiting would be meaningless, because the upstream supply would limit first. Maybe a thermal fuse?
is the schematic any good (intelligible, layout)?

My PCB layout (targetting JLCPCB 4 layer 50x50mm, and then hand soldering) looks like this:
3D View:
Note, the capacitor model is wrong, but lead distance and size should be correct

Top copper (signal and 5V power)

Back copper (mostly ground, some signal, power to soft-off touch sensor)

Inner copper 1 (left side 3.3V, right side 5V)

Inner copper 2 (ground plane)

I have applied all my of puny knowledge, used trace width calculators, looked at fab capabilities, copper balance, the works, but I am aware that I still know very little.
I would be grateful for hints about obvious problems.
Part references: (sorry, not enough rep to make all links clickable)

RP2040 datasheet
Raspberry Pi Pico datasheet
TTP223 touch sensor module: hxxps://www.amazon.co.jp/-/en/dp/B079BKVT98 and datasheet?hxxps://files.seeedstudio.com/wiki/Grove-Touch_Sensor/res/TTP223.pdf
BSS138 N-channel mosfet: hxxps://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/bss138-d.pdf
AO3401A P-channel mosfet: hxxps://www.aosmd.com/res/datasheets/AO3401A.pdf
TC74VHCT04AFT hex inverter: hxxps://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/74VHCT04AFT_datasheet_en_20170222.pdf?did=15620&prodName=74VHCT04AFT
MP34DT01 pdm microphone breakout: hxxps://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/049/977/original/MP34DT01-M.pdf
USB-C breakout board: not sure yet which one will fit in the case I am designing, but it will have the necessary pull-down resistors on the CC pins.
USB-C connector spec: hxxps://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/USB%20Type-C%20Spec%20R2.0%20-%20August%202019.pdf


Please don't use the word thingy or thing to describe what your circuit is intended to do because it imparts zero information. In other words, what are you trying to design?

@Andyaka, ok I agree, it wasn't the best wording. I added a paragraph hopefully explaining the end goal better.
